# Are there ensembles for non-equilibrium cases?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, statistics, non-equilibrium

Are there thermodynamic [ensembles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_ensemble_(mathematical_physics)) for off-equilibrium systems? 
The entropy is defined, so we should be able to extract some statistics on the system.

Comment: The citation list [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fluctuation_theorem) looks intriguing.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30448/non-equilibrium-statistical-mechanics?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. Non-equilibrium ensemble theory is, however, a highly specialized topic in the field of kinetic theory and there is no well established definition of a non-equilibrium ensemble, but rather different extensions to the Gibbs ensemble covering non-equilibrium cases. One frequently cited book in this field is "Nonequilibrium Statistical Mechanics" by Byung Chan Eu.

A pair of popular review articles is by  D. Jou, J. Casas-Vazquez, and G. Lebon:

Extended irreversible thermodynamics, Rep. Prog. Phys. 51, 1105 (1988)

Extended irreversible thermodynamics revisited, Rep. Prog. Phys. 62, 1035 (1998)